# Пропадает wifi

Tags: windows, wifi

Доброго времени суток! Такая проблема - есть неттоп, подключенный к плазменной панели, и у него постоянно пропадает wifi. В чем может быть проблема? И как определить источник проблемы?

Comment: Что именно пропадает, сигнал, ip, доступ во внешнюю сеть ?

Comment: сигнал пропадает

Comment: я уже обновил все, что можно, вплоть до bios

Comment: А точка доступа какая и где? Сигнал нормальный или на грани? У меня была как-то такая проблемка - через три бетонные стены. Вылечилось заменой роутера на более мощный (по WiFi).

Answer (score 1):

мало информации, опиши подробнеекак неттоп подключен к панели? через роутер?как определили что пропадает сигнал именно на неттопе? может связь рвется со стороны панели или роутера?что пишется в журнале системы неттопа?

попробуй пререключиться на другой каналпопробуй внешний WiFi адаптер

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема в отдельной квартире с телефоном на безе Android. Wi-fi раздавал роутер D-Link Dir-300. При этом все остальные девайсы подключались и работали нормально. Проблема пропала сама собой с заменой роутера.